# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in rxjs

Tags: rxjs

I am new to Angular 6.X and rxjs. I am trying to implement observable for the click operation. its pulling data through RestApi, but getting below exception at data['list'].map, I have tried different approaches, but none of them worked out.

```
get(): Observable<ProgramOwnerVulnerability[]> {
        //explicitly do not type this get, due to list structure returned
        return this.http
            .get(this.programListUrl)
            .pipe(map((data) => {
                //map data appropriately into the correct type
                return data['list'].map((programOwnerVulnerabilityJson) => {
                    return new ProgramOwnerVulnerability(programOwnerVulnerabilityJson);
                });
            }));
    }
```

**Exception:**

```
core.js:1598 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at MapSubscriber.project (program-owner.service.ts:29)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:81)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:85)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:136)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:20)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
```

Comment: data['list'] is undefined. shouldnt it be data.list?

Comment: Hi, i tried data.list, it throws compilation error (propety list does not exist on type.

Comment: seems like the property `list` doesn't exist on `data`